# Why is IE refusing to render a swf on my site?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, swfobject

Why is IE refusing to render a swf on my site?
[www.quickguitartuner.com](http://www.quickguitartuner.com)

What could cause that to happen? Chrome and Firefox can open it but IE9 won't show the swf.

The page's code:

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="pt-br">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Quick Guitar Tuner</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'my-site-id-on-analytics']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>



</head>


<body>

<p align="center">
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000" id="obj1" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" border="0" width="900" height="550">
    <param name="movie" value="Flash/bin/main2_secure.swf">
    <param name="quality" value="High">
    <embed src="Flash/main2_secure.swf" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" name="obj1" width="900" height="550" quality="High">
    <div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=127418320673531&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="www.quickguitartuner.com" send="false" layout="button_count" width="90" show_faces="false" font="" style="position:relative; left:395px; top:-217px" ></fb:like>

    </object>

</p>
<!--<p align="center">
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-1830251538744722";
/* Quick Guitar Tuner */
google_ad_slot = "9658449272";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;

</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
</p>//-->

<div align=center><a href='http://www.quickguitartuner.com'>
    <img src='http://contador.s12.com.br/img-5234ayx9-57.gif' border='0' alt='contador de visitas gratis'></a></div>



<p align="center" style="position:relative; left:403px; top:-310px">
    <g:plusone href="www.quickguitartuner.com"></g:plusone>
</p>

<p align="center" style="position:relative; left:403px; top:-380px">
    <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="horizontal">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
</p>

<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-24145583-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is something wrong with your code: `<param name="movie" value="Flash/bin/main2_secure.swf">
` and ` <embed src="Flash/main2_secure.swf"` the both path are different

Comment: `<param>` value is set to `value="Flash/bin/main2_secure.swf"` and `<embed>` value is set to `src="Flash/main2_secure.swf"`

Comment: file not found from this path: Flash/bin/main2_secure.swf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The urls in your movie param and embed tags are different.  Because IE reads from the embed and the other browsers use the value in `<param movie=` this will cause an issue if the file doesn't exist in both locations.

Answer (score 1):

Also, try using [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed your swf. Takes alot of the guess work out and there's less room for error.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="PATH/TO/swfobject.js"></script>

<div id="obj1">Replacement Flash Content goes here.</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var params = {
    wmode: "opaque",
    scaleMode: "noScale",
    bgColor: "#FFFFFF", 
    allowFullScreen: true
};
var flashvars ={};
var attributes = {
    id: "obj1",
    name: "obj1"
};

if (typeof swfobject != "undefined") {
    swfobject.embedSWF("Flash/bin/main2_secure.swf", "obj1", "900", "550", "10.0.0", null, flashvars, params, attributes);
}
</script>
```

Comment: edited with an example, but I did provide a link to the swfobject homepage, which has documentation and examples.

Comment: Several - makes it easier to provide flashvars, params, etc. , you won't have to write out attributes twice, it has player version detection built-in, and allows you to easily provide replacement content. Also it's pretty much the industry standard for swf embedding. You've already awarded the above answer correct, so just check the link I provided initially if you want some more info about it.

Answer (score 1):

Check your SWF sources - they differ. I'd guess the path you use for embed does not exists but the Param one does.

Add the /bin/ in and you'll be set.

Answer (score 1):

```
<param> value is set to 

value="Flash/bin/main2_secure.swf" 

and <embed> value is set to 

src="Flash/main2_secure.swf"
```

Both paths should be same.